Failed upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04
Tried to upgrade from 22.04 to 24, and now the GUI won't run. I also cannot connect to the Wi-Fi from the command line.
When I try to restart networkmanager, it says some library curl missing, but I can't download it. I also get a libgio not found error.
What can I do? Should I try to run it from USB? Or all is gone? Can I perhaps copy libgio-2.0 files from the USB somehow, and paste them where required?

Use a working system to create a LiveUSB. Boot the LiveUSB. Enter the "Try Ubuntu" environment. Use that environment to preserve all your data onto some other media. Then try a non-destructive reinstall (without formatting). If that fails, then do a destructive reinstall (with formatting).

I moved the libgio files from the Live 24.04 USB, and that resolved the issue (had a few more issues, but it was not difficult to solve). If you have a problem going from 22.04 to 24, add a comment, I'll try to help.
libgio files that were copied are in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
